# How do I execute a window function repeatedly in GatsbyJS/ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, typeerror, gatsby

I'm trying to repeatedly execute a window function when a GatsbyJS/ReactJS page is created. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Example extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.Foo();
  }

  Foo() {
    console.log(typeof window);
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.setTimeout(
        (() => {
          console.log("bar");
        },
        200)
      )();
    }
  }

  render(){
    return {
      <>
      </>
    }
  }
}
export default Example;
```

My question is why do I keep receiving a `TypeError: window.setTimeout(...) is not a function`. `window` is defined, but I can't use any of its methods. The function is going to modify the state in the future, so has to run during the mounting phase after the react component is rendered. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: unrelated to the question, but conventionally in javascript class methods are not uppercased; you also want to remove the curly bracket around the jsx or use parenthesis instead, so `return (<></>)` instead of `return {<></>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically calling `setTimeout(...)()`, which throws error because `setTimeout(...)` doesn't return a function.

```
  window.setTimeout(
    (() => {
      console.log("bar");
    },
    200)
  )(); 
   ^^
```

There's also an unnecessary pair of parenthesis there as well. You should be doing this:

```
window.setTimeout(() => { ... }, 200);
```